# AWS install fails: IAM instance profile already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I was installing openshift 4.4.9 on my AWS Cluster using Installer Provisioned Infrastructure (IPI), I wasn't successful to spin up my openshift cluster on AWS. Because of below error.

```
INFO Creating infrastructure resources...
ERROR
ERROR Error: Error creating IAM instance profile ocp4-925gm-bootstrap- 
 profile: EntityAlreadyExists: 
Instance Profile ocp4-925gm-bootstrap-profile already exists.
ERROR   status code: 409, request id: b6918967-774c-44c1-8b92-02ac7388f87c
ERROR
ERROR   on ../../../tmp/openshift-install-584826335/bootstrap/main.tf line 46, in resource 
"aws_iam_instance_profile" "bootstrap":
 ERROR   46: resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bootstrap" {

ERROR Error: Error creating IAM instance profile ocp4-925gm-worker-profile: EntityAlreadyExists: 
Instance Profile ocp4-925gm-worker-profile already exists.
ERROR   status code: 409, request id: 3b5d2b9c-28fe-4c95-b622-7a80af45dfb6
ERROR
ERROR   on ../../../tmp/openshift-install-584826335/iam/main.tf line 5, in resource 
 "aws_iam_instance_profile" "worker":
ERROR    5: resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "worker" {
ERROR Error: Error creating IAM instance profile ocp4-925gm-master-profile: EntityAlreadyExists: 
Instance Profile ocp4-925gm-master-profile already exists.
ERROR   status code: 409, request id: 072d86e1-3508-4d59-a6ab-2ed647251056
ERROR
ERROR   on ../../../tmp/openshift-install-584826335/master/main.tf line 9, in 
resource 
 "aws_iam_instance_profile" "master":
ERROR    9: resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "master" {
FATAL failed to fetch Cluster: failed to generate asset "Cluster": failed to 
create cluster: failed 
to apply using Terraform
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution to Fix**

1. Manually deletion is recommended in this case.
2. List your roles and then apply delete to the instance profiles.

   ```
   $ aws iam list-roles
   $ aws --region=<region-name> iam delete-instance-profile --instance-profile-name <profile_name>
   ```

Example Given Below

```
    $ aws --region=us-east-1 iam delete-instance-profile --instance-profile-name  ocp4-925gm-master-profile

    $ aws --region=us-east-1 iam delete-instance-profile --instance-profile-name  ocp4-925gm-worker-profile
```

[Reference Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_delete.html)

Comment: What is DPP? It would help if you linked to what that is because from your question and answer it's not clear why this would happen or what DPP is.

Comment: DPP is Digital Production Platform & I have rephrased my answer accordingly. Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Comment: Is this an internal thing? If so this question and answer combo doesn't really make sense with this. Could you strip out an extraneous information related to internal things so that it's useful for other people who might need to understand how to import things that have been lost from state.

Comment: Addressed, Thanks for your support.

Comment: should use this command to get the instant profile:
`aws --profile artem iam list-instance-profile`

Answer (score 0):

**Clarification:** Before deleting iam profile on aws make sure that you do not have any aws ec2 instances running with the instance profile you are about to delete. Deleting a role or instance profile that's associated with a running instance will break any applications running on the instance. for documentation use this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/delete-instance-profile.html).

`aws iam delete-instance-profile --instance-profile-name <profile-name>`